# How do I switch images before clicking a button in Python using TKinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

In the following code, I want to display picture1.jpg as soon as button1 is pressed.  After some time, I want to display picture2.jpg.  In the following case, only picture2.jpg is displayed 5 seconds after the button1 is pressed.  How can I change pictures?

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

def show_image():
    while True:
        image = Image.open("picture1.jpg")
        tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        x = canvas.create_image(400, 300, image=tk_img)
        canvas.itemconfigure(x, state=NORMAL)
        # I want to show picture1.jpg now
        time.sleep(5)  #This is a dummy because it takes a while for picture2.jpg
        #Now I can show picture2.jpg
        image = Image.open("picture2.jpg")
        tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        x = canvas.create_image(400, 300, image=tk_img)
        canvas.itemconfigure(x, state=NORMAL)
        yield

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=850, height=750)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

button1 = Button(
    root, text="Insert next device and then take a picture", command=show_image().next, anchor='w',
    width=50, activebackground="#33B5E5" ,fg = "blue" , font=("Arial", 24))
button1.grid(row=1, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as a general rule you should never call `sleep` in the main thread of a GUI. It causes your whole program to pause -- buttons won't work, the screen won't update, etc.

Tkinter has a way to run code in the future. Change the image, and then use this function to change it back later. Roughly speaking, it would look like this:

```
def show_image(path):
    image = Image.open(path)
    tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    x = canvas.create_image(400, 300, image=tk_img)

def switch_images():
    show_image("picture1.jpg")
    root.after(5000, show_image, "picture2.jpg")
```

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I have used Tkinter. I added "switch_images()" directly after x = canvas.create_image(400, 300, image=tk_img) and the image did not change.   Where do I put the call switch_images()?  Does it matter that x is not defined? By the way, thanks for the tip about not using "sleep".